# Android Studio: Error on including 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.4.0' in gradle file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I added following dependency to my gradle file compile 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.4.0'. and then after doing a clean gradle build its gives the following error in layout [image]

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

androidplot custom views must not support layout preview.

If you want to see the rest of your code, you can do what it says and surround the involved code in `View.isInEditMode();` for example:

```
public MyCustomView(Context c) {
    if(!View.isInEditMode() {
        addView(androidPlotView); // this is the line we are avoiding when using the layout preview
    }
}
```

---

Other than the layout preview not working, when you run your application on a device it will work normally - this is not an error in your app, only in the layout preview tool.

Comment: Androidplot supports layout preview as you can see in the [quickstart video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEFkzQY_wWI).  The video is for an older version but I've personally verified 1.4.0 works as well.  Also the stack trace references AppCompatImageView, among others which is not used anywhere in the androidplot lib and  is not an Androidplot component.